# FreshMvvm PushNewNavigationServiceModal not working

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, navigation, freshmvvm

I'm trying to change from `FreshNavigationContainer` to `FreshMasterDetailNavigationContainer` when the user is loggedin within the method `SuccessfulLogin` by using freshMvvm method `PushNewNavigationServiceModal` but nothing is happening.

```
    public void SuccessfulLogin()
    {
        App.IsLoggedIn = true;
        var masterDetailNav = new FreshMasterDetailNavigationContainer();
        masterDetailNav.Init("Menu");
        masterDetailNav.AddPage<ProfilePageModel>("Profile", null);
        CoreMethods.PushNewNavigationServiceModal(masterDetailNav);
    }
```

**Edit** :
I just noticed that after using this method navigation isn't working anymore.

Comment: Do you get an exception or anything alike? Did the implementation work previously?

Comment: Nope i'm not getting anything, it's the firsrt time i'm using this méthod so I couldn't tell but other methods are working juste fine.

Comment: I suppose reading this complete [documentation of FreshMvvm](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm) would help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **CoreMethods.SwitchOutRootNavigation**

First Setup your NavigationStacks

```
public class NavigationStacks
{
    public static string LoginNavigationStack = "LoginNavigationStack";
    public static string MainAppStack = "MainAppStack";
}
```

In you App.xaml.cs define the Navigations

```
FreshNavigationContainer loginMain;
FreshMasterDetailNavigationContainer masterDetailNav;

var loginPage = FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel<UserLoginPageModel>();
loginMain = new FreshNavigationContainer(loginPage, NavigationStacks.LoginNavigationStack);

var masterDetailNav = new FreshMasterDetailNavigationContainer(NavigationStacks.MainAppStack);
masterDetailNav.Init("Menu");
masterDetailNav.AddPage<ProfilePageModel>("Profile", null);
```

Then in your Login ViewModel

```
public void SuccessfulLogin()
{
    App.IsLoggedIn = true;
    CoreMethods.SwitchOutRootNavigation(NavigationStacks.MainAppStack);
}
```